# Run automation on a record routed by omnichannel

Tags: omnichannel

As per [this article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000337822&type=1&mode=1), Salesforce doesn't run automation when a record is being routed via omnichannel. I also checked via debug logs - when omnichannel routes a record, no debug logs are spawned.

We've got a requirement to set a datetime field when a case has been routed to an agent via omnichannel.

Is there a way to execute an automation on when a case has been routed via omnichannel? Or other ways to fulfill the requirements? The only idea I've got now is to use scheduler, which has its disadvantages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a workaround. Whenever a case is assigned by omnichannel to an agent - [AgentWork](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_agentwork.htm) record is created. Triggers(and other automation) work on the record.